# ionic ion-input vs input - keyboard hides control

Tags: ionic-framework, input, mobile, keyboard

On iPad (Air 2 iPadOS v15.x) in Safari or Chrome using the Web only, when touching ion-input (v6.x) control at the bottom of the screen, the keyboard shows up and hides the control.  Changing the ion-input for a standard HTML input, it doesn't hide it and the control is positioned correctly above the keyboard.
Why is that?  How can I have the ion-input behave the same as the input?
With the ion-input, the cursor has to be already in the control for it to work as expected but the first time you touch it...doesn't work.

Easy to reproduce, create a new ionic app and drop an ion-input and input side-by-side at the bottom of the page and test.

The application is not built in iOS, only runs in the Web Browser.
I can't believe there is no straight answers on that thousands of us must have no?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this link `https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/keyboard#keyboardresize`

Comment: as I stated, the app is not running as a PWA or built as iOS native, it simply runs in a browser.  This will not have any effect.